# Querying the database postgreSQL

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

Good afternoon, I study the library for working with postgresql from python, it’s written in the description:

> Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.

I want to output from the `reports` table, columns `object, data`
I tried to make a function like this:

```
def select(self, column, table):
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        stmt = sql.SQL('SELECT {} FROM {}').format(
            sql.Identifier(column),
            sql.Identifier(table))
        cursor.execute(stmt)
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
```

But I get an error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column "object, data" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "object, data" FROM "object"
```

I managed to achieve the desired result using the function:

```
def select(self, column, table):
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT %s FROM %s" %(column,table))
        return cursor.fetchall()
```

Can you please tell me how to make a function without using `%s`?

Comment: Read the whole section of the documentation again careful and read the example below the large red box which tells you how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of passing the string columns, you should have an list of the columns names you want to pass. Now you can use `sql.SQL(', ').join()` to join them.

```
def select(self, columns, table):
    with conn.cursor() as cursor:
        stmt = sql.SQL('SELECT {} FROM {}').format(
            sql.SQL(', ').join(sql.Identifier(n) for n in columns),
            sql.Identifier(table))
        cursor.execute(stmt)
        for row in cursor:
            print(row)
```